# iOS 10 - didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDevice only called the first time

Tags: xcode, apple-push-notifications, ios10

I'm having a problem where didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDevice only gets called the first time I call registerForRemoteNotifications after reinstalling the app, on iOS 10.

What's happening: after uninstalling the app and then running the app in debug from XCode, I tap "allow" on the in-app popup and I do get my log message for "did register for remote notifications with device token!", and I get a device token. This makes me hesitantly think that my certificate / provisioning profiles are OK. However, this device token doesn't seem to work for sending push notifications (might be a separate issue on the server), and after closing the app and reopening it, I only see "Push authorization granted: 1" and "Push registration starting." but no popup to allow push notifications, and no didRegister callback/token.

I tried finding solutions, but I couldn't find anyone for whom the didRegister function only shows the first time so I'm not sure what could be causing it.

This is the code that the app is using:

```
-(void)registerForNotifications
{
#if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
if(SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"10.0")) {
    // This part is irrelevant, doesn't get called on iOS 10
    -> some code for push notifications
}
else {
    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    center.delegate = self;
    [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error)
     {
         NSLog(@"push authorization granted: %d", granted);
         if(!error)
         {
             [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
             NSLog(@"Push registration starting.");
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"Push registration FAILED");
             NSLog(@"ERROR: %@ - %@", error.localizedFailureReason, error.localizedDescription);
             NSLog(@"SUGGESTIONS: %@ - %@", error.localizedRecoveryOptions, error.localizedRecoverySuggestion);
         }  
     }];
}
#endif
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDevice :(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    NSLog(@"did register for remote notifications with device!");
    [self handleNewDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(nonnull NSData *)deviceToken
{
    NSLog(@"did register for remote notifications with device token!");
    [self handleNewDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}
```

I'm hoping this is just something stupid on my side / with provisioning profiles or certificates, I'm not too experienced with iOS development yet. Do let me know if you could use any additional information.

**EDIT**
Alright, the underlying issue was that my code was calling unregisterForRemoteNotifications every time before calling register. Apparently, iOS10 had a change where calling unregister causes register not to work for a bunch of time after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks lie an iOS 10 bug and couple of more developers are complaining to experience similar issue here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63038.

From what I see, the subsequent attempts to call `registerForRemoteNotifications` after you have called `unregisterForRemoteNotifications` will *not* invoke any of:

- `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`
- nor `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError`

methods on AppDelegate. Basically you don't receive any callback from the iOS.

The only workaround that I am currently aware of, is to add *background fetch* capability to you Info.plist. I can confirm that this solved the issue for me, but you would need to evaluate whether that solution os plausible for you.

Comment: Ahh brilliant! Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I'm at the end of my work day so I can't try your fix, but I will update on this tomorrow :)

Comment: Alright, while the solution you suggested didn't do much for me, I did notice something else that mentioned in the topic you linked - "The problem seems to be that iOS 10 prevents registering for push notification with Apple in a manner of time (24h?) after unregistering". Apparently my app was calling unregister every time before reregistering. Thanks so much for the link!

Answer (score 0):

For me the only working *solution* was to use the old-style-registration in parallel:

```
center.requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .alert , .sound]) { (granted, error) in ... }

let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .sound, .alert], categories: nil)
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
```